# Unable to cast object of type 'PacketDotNet.EthernetPacket' to type 'SharpPcap.RawCapture'

Tags: c#, packet-sniffers, sharppcap

I've been following the guide over at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/sharppcap.aspx for implementing a simple packet sniffer.

I am getting an error while converting 'PacketDotNet.EthernetPacket' to 'SharpPcap.RawCapture'. Following is the piece of code that does the conversion part.

`SharpPcap.RawCapture nextPacket = (SharpPcap.RawCapture)(lvMessages.Items[packetIndex].Tag);`

I am not getting any compilation errors with this code. How should i convert this successfully ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you storing in lvMessages.Items[]? I'm not sure what this structure is or what type you are putting in there. You might provide a link to your code on pastebin to provide more context. Also, the SharpPcap and Packet.Net source packages have a whole set of example applications that might help.

Answer (score 0):

What are you storing in lvMessages.Items[]? I'm not sure what this structure is or what type you are putting in there. You might provide a link to your code on pastebin to provide more context. Also, the SharpPcap and Packet.Net source packages have a whole set of example applications that might help.